# Sybase proc throws error - Incorrect syntax neatr ','

Tags: sybase, powerbuilder, sybase-ase15

I am using Powerbuilder and Sybase in my application. I need to save Japanese characters from screen in a table. But when I try to update the existing row and click on save I get a DB error code 102, ERROR: Incorrect syntax near ','. 
I tried to update in the database table directly using update command and this works ok. But when I try the same from my application I get this error.
Please help.

Thx
Sharmistha

Comment: To get an answer, you might want to be more precise about what “save” means? Saving an object? A DataWindow? Data at runtime? Embedded SQL? DataWindow? PB version is also critical to this question; not all support Unicode. You might also be able to narrow down the question by using the tracing techniques described at http://www.techno-kitten.com/PowerBuilder_Help/Troubleshooting/Database_Irregularities/database_irregularities.html

Comment: Hello I have edited my question. Thx

Comment: What is the SQL being sent from your application to the database?  A database trace can show you this.  You are not providing enough information in your question.

Comment: Pre-PB10 or post-PB10? Pre- won’t have a chance unless it’s specifically a Japanese or Unicode version (they had both at different times). When you “directly update”, do you use the same syntax that PB generates? You can see this in the SQLPreview event (if this is a DataWindows... you haven’t said) or from a database trace.

Comment: Thx, I will try to follow the above suggestions